# Change projection of list of rasters in R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, sp, list

I am handed down some RData that contain a list of of raster stacks. The file structure is pretty challenging to manipulate. After doing `load()`, the data looks like this:

```
[[1]]
class      : RasterStack 
filename   : raster1 
dimensions : 82, 101, 8282, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 2.008502, 1.991304  (x, y)
extent     : 488240.2, 488443, 4950773, 4950937  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs 
names      :    Y2020 
min values : 24.14956 
max values : 24.14958 


[[2]]
class      : RasterStack 
filename   : raster2  
dimensions : 435, 157, 68295, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1.997977, 1.999499  (x, y)
extent     : 488481.3, 488795, 4950998, 4951868  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs 
names      :    Y2020 
min values : 20.94342 
max values : 22.16785 

...

[[n]]
class      : RasterStack 
filename   : raster_n 
dimensions : 225, 261, 58725, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1.998339, 1.998643  (x, y)
extent     : 484329.9, 484851.5, 4950577, 4951027  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs 
names      :    Y2020 
min values : 20.62384 
max values : 20.62384
```

I would like to reproject the list of rasters using `spTransform()` through `dplyr`. Here is my code:

```
utm18 <- "+proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"
new_crs_myrasterlist <- sapply(myrasterlist, function(x) spTransform(myrasterlist[[x]], CRSobj=utm18))
```

I also tried,

```
new_crs_myrasterlist <- sapply(myrasterlist, function(x) spTransform(myrasterlist[[x]], CRS(utm18)))
```

Both code gave me this error:

```
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'spTransform': invalid subscript type 'S4'
```

What am I missing? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

two things:

firstly the `invalid subscript type 'S4'` error is because `sapply` loops over elements of the list, not indexes, so inside your function `x` is one of the raster stacks, and so you are trying to subscript your list of stacks by a stack:

```
new_crs_myrasterlist <- sapply(myrasterlist, function(x) spTransform(myrasterlist[[x]], CRSobj=utm18))
```

Instead, you want something like:

```
new_crs_myrasterlist <- sapply(myrasterlist, function(x) spTransform(x, CRSobj=utm18))
```

or

```
new_crs_myrasterlist <- sapply(1:length(myrasterlist), function(i) spTransform(myrasterlist[[i]], CRSobj=utm18))
```

That gets the basic structure right, but this will still fail because `spTransform` doesn't work on rasters:

```
> new_crs_myrasterlist <- sapply(myrasterlist, function(x) spTransform(x, CRSobj=utm18))
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘spTransform’ for signature ‘"RasterStack", "character"’
```

Instead you need `projectRaster`:

```
> new_crs_myrasterlist <- sapply(myrasterlist, function(x) projectRaster(x, crs=utm18))
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. it did fix the the projection, however it eliminated the filename. Why is that? How do I keep it?

Comment: What filename? I can't see a filename anywhere except the RData file you mentioned. Once you have read the data into memory (with `load`) then any connection to that file is lost. R works (mostly) in memory, not on files, and data is loaded into memory using `load` and similar functions.

Comment: The files are structured like so:
```lang-js

class      : RasterStack 
filename   : raster1 
dimensions : 82, 101, 8282, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 2.008502, 1.991304  (x, y)
extent     : 488240.2, 488443, 4950773, 4950937  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs 
names      :    Y2020 
min values : 24.14956 
max values : 24.14958
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `spTransform` for this. You need `projectRaster`.

If `s` is a `RasterStack` or other `Raster*` object, you can do

```
utm18 <- "+proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=NAD83 +units=m"
sutm <- projectRaster(s, utm18)
```

And if `slst` is a list of Raster* objects you can do

```
slstutm <- lapply(slst, function(r) projectRaster(r, utm18))
```