# projectRaster on a list of rasters

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, list

I have two raster layers in a list format called `myrasterlist` that differ in extent and crs. The list looks like this:

```
[[1]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 540, 537, 289980  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent     : -26845.54, 26854.46, -27030.27, 26969.73  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=aeqd +lat_0=25.758355 +lon_0=-79.27114 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : All_Rasters_Scaled.asc 
names      : North 
values     : 0, 1  (min, max)


[[2]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 540, 537, 289980  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent     : -26866.45, 26833.55, -27003.87, 26996.13  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=aeqd +lat_0=25.6871 +lon_0=-79.29336 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : South 
values     : 0, 1  (min, max)
```

While these are only 2 rasters in this list, in reality the number of rasters can be >2. I'm looking to use a function that reprojects all rasters all at once using projectRaster(). I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396769/change-projection-of-list-of-rasters-in-r) thread, but the solutions offered don't work for my rasters and i fail to understand why.

Here is what i tried:

```
sapply(myrasterlist, function(x) projectRaster(x, crs=proj4string(myrasterlist[[length(myrasterlist)]])))

[[1]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 550, 547, 300850  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent     : -25121, 29579, -19631.7, 35368.3  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=aeqd +lat_0=25.6871 +lon_0=-79.29336 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : North 
values     : 0, 0.9984284  (min, max)


[[2]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 550, 547, 300850  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent     : -27366.45, 27333.55, -27503.87, 27496.13  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=aeqd +lat_0=25.6871 +lon_0=-79.29336 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : South 
values     : 0, 1  (min, max)


Warning message:
In projectRaster(x, crs = proj4string(myrasterlist[[length(myrasterlist)]])) :
  input and ouput crs are the same
```

What am i not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

You are reprojecting to the last raster's CRS. It's a bit confusing, I recommend you to:

1. Project to a known CRS (it could be stored in an object as well)
2. Use a raster as template

Also, since this process is usually slow, use `terra` package to speed up computations. Reproducible data:

```
library(terra)

# Geographic WGS 84 raster
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)

s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")) 
crs(s, proj = T)
# [1] "+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

myrasterlist <- list(s,s)
```

Using the first approach:

```
# first approach
lapply(myrasterlist, function(x) project(x, y = 'epsg:4326'))
# [[1]]
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 77, 101, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 9.005454e-06, 9.005454e-06  (x, y)
# extent      : 0, 0.0009095508, 2.944547e-06, 0.0006963645  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# source      : memory 
# colors RGB  : 1, 2, 3 
# names       : red, green, blue 
# min values  :   0,     0,    0 
# max values  : 255,   255,  255 
# 
# [[2]]
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 77, 101, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 9.005454e-06, 9.005454e-06  (x, y)
# extent      : 0, 0.0009095508, 2.944547e-06, 0.0006963645  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# source      : memory 
# colors RGB  : 1, 2, 3 
# names       : red, green, blue 
# min values  :   0,     0,    0 
# max values  : 255,   255,  255
```

Using the second approach:

```
# second aprroach
lapply(myrasterlist, function(x) project(x, y = r))
# [[1]]
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 90, 95, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
# extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# source      : memory 
# colors RGB  : 1, 2, 3 
# names       : red, green, blue 
# min values  : NaN,   NaN,  NaN 
# max values  : NaN,   NaN,  NaN 
# 
# [[2]]
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 90, 95, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
# extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# source      : memory 
# colors RGB  : 1, 2, 3 
# names       : red, green, blue 
# min values  : NaN,   NaN,  NaN 
# max values  : NaN,   NaN,  NaN
```

In this last example, both extents don't match, and `project` is projecting over `r`'s extent, that's why we got `NaN`values.

Comment: the reason i project to the last raster's CRS is because the following code works for 2 rasters, whereby both rasters have the crs of the second raster object: r1.1 <- projectRaster(r1, r2). I would also want to retain the aeqd projection. But am unsure how to make the crs more general. Also, did you mean to type "myrasterlist <- list(s,s)"? If i replace with "myrasterlist <- list(r,s)" then the rasters do not get equal resolution nor extent.

Comment: I tested your suggested second approach after converting RasterLayers to SpatRasters so that these could be used by Terra. And it works on 2 rasters whereby i set y = myrasterlist[[length(myrasterlist)]]. Does this make sense? Or should y refer to the first raster?

Comment: `myrasterlist <- list(s,s)` was for making a reproducible example. With `myrasterlist[[length(myrasterlist)]]` you are selecting the last raster in tath list.

Comment: Ok got it. Could you please explain how the maximum value of raster 1 changes from 1 to 0.9984284 (value in my OP) or to 0.9868895 after converting to SpatRaster and applying your suggested second solution?

Comment: Because when you project there are two options (using this function, there are other methods): 1.- use bilinear method for computing new values (this case, useful for continuous data). 2.- use nearest neighbor preserving the same value (useful for categorical data)